# How to configure Win2008 to generate crash dump

Tags: windows-server-2008, crash-dumps

I am running my C++ servi ce on Win2008 server machine. It crashes randomaly, and i do not know why. This is happening on multiple machines in customer site.

How can i configure the system to auto generate a dump of the process?
I need a method that will require minimal installations and UI, preferably only some registry hacks.

Thanks.

[edit] waiting...

Answer (score 2):

You can use Windows Error Reporting locally on a machine without having to involve Microsoft and without having to sign your code. WER can be configured to store local copies of dumps. The MSDN documentation is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx

It's a simple, well thought-out system, and is only a couple of registry settings to configure.

Answer (score 0):

If your customer allows then i would suggest you to install DebugDiag from Microsoft. You can configure the tool to generate dumps when your application crashes and ask them to send you those dumps. I have used this quite often and found it to be successfull. If any help required please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Sign your executable then register with Microsoft for [Windows Error Reporting](https://winqual.microsoft.com/) (the signing certificate costs but WER is free).  This will then collect the crash logs when the user hits the 'Send to Microsoft' button.  These logs will then sit there until you log in to retrieve them.  This requires no other installations on the user's machine.